# swipe between views using scrollview - swift

Tags: ios, swift

in viewDidLoad :

```
viewPager.dataSource = self
```

--

```
extension DetailsViewController:ViewPagerDataSource{
func numberOfItems(_ viewPager:ViewPager) -> Int {
    return dict!.count
}


 func viewAtIndex(_ viewPager:ViewPager, index:Int, view:UIView?) -> UIView {






     func viewAtIndex(_ viewPager:ViewPager, index:Int, view:UIView?) -> UIView {


    return  view
```

the result is slow , it does not show the animation of transition maybe cuz I return the scrollview view not normal view , and when I swipe to left it shows nothing (swipe backwards) , is there anything better to implement ? 
thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, and then you post a BUNCH of code, including code that's irrelevant to your question. You should only post the parts that directly relate to your question.

It looks like what you want is a `UIPageViewController`. That manages an array of view controllers, each of which holds the contents of one page. You can either user it with a page curl animation like iBooks, or a scrolling mode. You want the scrolling mode.

If you search in the Xcode help (or online, it looks like the link to download the app isn't in Xcode 8) on "PhotoScroller" You'll find a demo app that illustrates how it works.

That app is written in Objective-C, but it will at least show you the UI it offers.

In order to use a `UIPageViewController` you'll have to restructure your detail view controller to manage an array of child view controllers instead of only using a single view controller.

If you want side scrolling AND up and down scrolling among a grid of tiles then you want a collection view instead, but that's more work to set up.